# Where can I change shortcut for expo in current workspace only (ALT+SHIFT+up)?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I need to change shortcut for "Expo mode for all windows in the current workspace only" because is in conflict with usual netbeans shortcuts. But I cannot find it in ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager). Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

This function is provided by the Scale plugin. You can change the shortcut in **CompizConfig Settings Manager ▸ Scale ▸ Bindings ▸ Initiate Window Picker**.